# Make an easy class support concurrency

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a simple bank account class that needs to pass the following test

```
import sys
import threading
import time
import unittest

from bank_account import BankAccount


class BankAccountTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_can_handle_concurrent_transactions(self):
        account = BankAccount()
        account.open()
        account.deposit(1000)

        self.adjust_balance_concurrently(account)

        self.assertEqual(account.get_balance(), 1000)

    def adjust_balance_concurrently(self, account):
        def transact():
            account.deposit(5)
            time.sleep(0.001)
            account.withdraw(5)

        # Greatly improve the chance of an operation being interrupted
        # by thread switch, thus testing synchronization effectively
        try:
            sys.setswitchinterval(1e-12)
        except AttributeError:
            # For Python 2 compatibility
            sys.setcheckinterval(1)

        threads = [threading.Thread(target=transact) for _ in range(1000)]
        for thread in threads:
            thread.start()
        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()
```

I tried to read the threading documentation but I found it a bit confusing to try and apply to my situation. What I tried is this:

```
class BankAccount(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.state = False
        self.balance = 0
        Thread().start()

    def get_balance(self):
        if self.state:
            return self.balance
        else:
            raise ValueError

    def open(self):
        self.state = True

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount
```

It is clearly wrong. My aim is just to understand how to get the class to handle a thread switch. If I have not included important information, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to make sure that multiple threads cannot modify the balance at same time.

The `deposit()` function, although it seems that it is a single step, is a multi step operation.

```
old_balance = self.balance
new_balance = old_balance + deposit
self.balance = new_balance
```

If thread switch happens in the middle of a deposit, it can corrupt the data.

For example suppose Thread 1 calls `deposit(10)` and Thread 2 calls `deposit(20)`, initial balance is 100

```
# Inside thread 1
old_balance1 = self.balance      
new_balance1 = old_balance1 + 10 
# Thread switches to thread 2    
old_balance2 = self.balance      
new_balance2 = old_balance2 + 20 
self.balance = new_balance2      # balance = 120
# Thread switches back to thread 1
self.balance = new_balance1      # balance = 110
```

Here final balance is `110` while it should have been `130`.

The solution is to prevent two threads from writing to the `balance` variable simultaneously. We can make use of `Lock`s to accomplish this.

```
import threading

class BankAccount:

    def open(self):
        self.balance = 0
        # initialize lock
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def deposit(self, val):
        # if another thread has acquired lock, block till it releases
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.balance += val
        self.lock.release()

    def withdraw(self, val):
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.balance -= val
        self.lock.release()

    def get_balance(self):
        return self.balance
```